# Non-conjugated roots in the eigenequation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE:

$$y'' - iky = 0, k > 0$$

I tried to solve it via the eigenequation, and the result is
$r^2 = ik$, $r = \pm k(\sqrt{2}/2 + i\sqrt{2}/2)$

And the roots are non-conjugated...

What should I do?

Comment: Conjugate roots appear when the equation has real coefficients. This does not prevent you to solve the ODE.

Comment: @ShawnWang: Did the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: @Ju'x Thanks! For both editing and commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Assume the solution is:

$$y(t) = e^{m t}$$

Find the second derivative, substitute into $(1)$ and solve.

**Spoiler** Hover over the following area.

> $ \displaystyle y(t) = y_1(t) + y_2(t) = c_1 e^{-(1+i) \sqrt{k} t/\sqrt{2}} + c_2 e^{(1+i) \sqrt{k} t/\sqrt{2}} $

Comment: The spoiler area is grey for me...

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you! I used a same equation that y = c1 * exp (r1*x) + c2 * exp (r2*x) :)

Comment: @ShawnWang: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: How has this helpful post gone without a TU! Need to fix that! +1

Comment: Yes it is POETS Day! One week down for me, one to go at L'Hospital!